# how to pass property value to property of another class in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I want to pass SecondViewModel **SecondProperty** value to ViewModel **myProperty**  and  show the value on **TextBlock**.
i want the coding to be done in SecondViewModel.
Hope it is clear.

Thanks for the help in Advance.

**View:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=myProperty}"/>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private int _myProperty;
public int myProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set { _myProperty = value; OnPropertyChanged("myProperty"); }
}
```

**SecondViewModel:**

```
private int _secondProperty;
public int SecondProperty
{
   get { return _secondProperty; }
   set { _secondProperty = value; OnPropertyChanged("SecondProperty"); }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 view models for a single view? It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Actually, it does make sense. For example, a `DataGrid` should have an `ObservableCollection<OtherVM>` so it's not that weird.

Comment: i have 2 views and 2 viewmodels and when first view textbox is updated i want to show it on  second view textblock

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, assuming that `ViewModel` holds a collection of `SecondViewModel` items, you need to set the `PropertyChangedEvent` for each instance of `SecondViewModel` to trigger `ViewModel.myProperty` to refresh. e.g. ...

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private List<SecondViewModel> _secondViewModels = new List<SecondViewModel>();

    public IEnumerable<SecondViewModel> SecondViewModels => _secondViewModels;

    public int myProperty => _secondViewModels.Sum(vm => vm.SecondProperty);

    public void AddSecondViewModel(SecondViewModel vm)
    {
        _secondViewModels.Add(vm);
        vm.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(myProperty));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(myProperty));
    }
}
```

As an aside, you should never call `OnPropertyChanged()` with a "magic string" - use `nameof()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you need that, you should create a VM DataSource to create a dependency in your first VM.

```
public class YourViewModelDataSource
 {

private ViewModel viewModel;
private SecondViewModel secondViewModel;

public YourViewModelDataSource(ViewModel viewModel, SecondViewModel secondViewModel)
    {
      this.viewModel = viewModel;
      this.secondViewModel = secondViewModel;
    }

public void CreateDataSource()
    {
      this.secondViewModel.PropertyChanged += this.OnSecondViewModelPropertyChanged;
    }

private void OnSecondViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                //As pointed in comments, you need to have the second property in your first ViewModel then do this.
                case "SecondProperty":
                    this.viewModel.myProperty = this.secondViewModel.SecondProperty;
                    break;
            }
        }
  }
```

When you create your VMs then use this class to create the dependency. Every time `SecondViewModel` SecondProperty changes, the `ViewModel` myProperty will be raised. I hope it's clear, let me know if you need something else

Comment: Check my edit. BTW, don't do it inside your `SecondViewModel` try to apply SOLID :) Create a new class with that responsibility